# Is every subgroup in a solvable group's composition series, also a normal subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

I am trying to understand this proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1889305/74378

To summarize what is going on there, $G$ is a solvable group with composition series

$$ 1\triangleleft G_1 \triangleleft \cdots \triangleleft G_n = G$$

At one point this answer selects a $G_{i+1}$ which is abelian and is in the series.  From this fact, the answerer infers $G_{i+1}\trianglelefteq G$.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding this step, but I can't think of a reason why a subgroup in the series should always be normal in $G$.  Or if it has to do with the subgroup being abelian, I'm still not sure why that would entail that it is normal in $G$.  If we select $g\in G$ then we would need to show $gG_{i+1}g^{-1} = G_{i+1}$ but I can't think of how this relates to two elements in $G_{i+1}$ commuting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't conclude that. There are many normal series in which not all subgroups (including abelian subgroups) are normal in $G$. However, if $G$ is solvable then there **exists** some normal series with abelian quotients in which every subgroup is normal in $G$. For example, the derived series of $G$. (which indeed comes to the trivial group because $G$ is solvable) So I believe in the answer it is assumed you choose such a series from the beginning.

Comment: I would call these *sub*normal series.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki Yes exactly. Saying that a series is a normal series strongly suggests that every subgroup in the series is normal. The fact that some authors have defined a normal series to be one in which each subgroup is normal in the next is no reason to perpetuate this confusion reminology.